# Limit point of a domain $D$ for functions $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My book provides the following theorem:

Let $x_0$ be a limit point of the domain $D$ of a function $f$. Then $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ exists iff for all sequences $x_1, x_2, \ldots \in D$, $x_i \neq x_0$ that converge to $x_0$, the sequence $f(x_1), f(x_2), \ldots$ converges.

Two questions:

1. I am sure we can construct functions from $D \neq \mathbb{R}$ so there are no limit points. For example, suppose we have a function only defined on the integers. Then there are no limit points. Since the function will be only continuous at those isolated integer points, is it right to say that a limit exists at those points?
2. This is tangentially related, but is it right to say that if function is defined with domain $D = \mathbb{R}$ then every point in the domain is also a limit point?

Comment: It's common to only **define** the notion of "limit of a function $f$ at $p$" when $p$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$. So if that domain has no limit points at all we can not talk about limits of $f$ at all. For the domain $\Bbb R$ we can discuss it for *any* point of the reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.The definition of limit of a function $f:D\to \Bbb R$ in a **limit point** $x_0$ of $D$ ($x_0\in \overline D$) says that $lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=l:\iff 
\forall \epsilon>0 \exists δ>0:0<|x-x_0|<δ\Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$.

The definition of continuity of a function $f:D\to \Bbb R$ in a **$x_0\in D$** says that
$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists δ>0:|x-x_0|<δ\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

As you see, we need a limit point for limit but a point in domain of $f$ for continuity. *If* $x_0 \in D$ is also a limit point of $D$, then we take limits; *if it is not*, then we do not take limits (continuity *is not* about limits necessarilly).
If then $D:=\Bbb Z$, then the definition of continuity is satisfied *automatically* (and *without* limits).

2. Of course, every point of $\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $\Bbb R$, that is $\overline {\Bbb R}=\Bbb R$.